# How to count whitespace in line? [JAVA]

Tags: java

If I have this code for counting specific word in a file and I want to count the whitespace in line, how can i write it?

Ex. I want to count whitespace in "int a = 0;"

output: whitespace are 3.

**Thank you very much.**

My code:

```
public static  void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (new File("/Users/BooMMacbookProRetina/Desktop/C/Resource [Java Sample file]/GradeCal.java"));

    int c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0;

    String t1 = "int";
    String t2 = " ";
    String t3 = ";";

    while (in.hasNext()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        line = line.trim();
        if (line.length() >0 ){

            int k = -1;
            while (true){   //Count System
                k = line.indexOf(t1, k+1);
                if (k<0) break;
                c1++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number integers are: " +c1);
    System.out.println("Total number of whitespace in int line are: " +c2);

}
```

Resource file for counting: [Download from my dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66286522/Java%20Thesis/Resource%20%5BJava%20Sample%20file%5D/GradeCal.java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
int a = str.length() - str.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
```

for your requirement

```
int whitespaceCount = 0;

//inside while loop
if (Character.isWhitespace(text.charAt(i)) {
        whitespaceCount++
    }
```

Comment: if i want to create while loop for count whitespace in line, how can i write it?

Comment: 'int whitespaceCount = 0;

//inside while loop
if (Character.isWhitespace(text.charAt(i)) {
        whitespaceCount++
    }'

Comment: You mean
while (in.hasNext()){
   String line = in.nextLine();
   line = line.trim();
   if (line.length() >0 ){
    
    int k = -1;
    while (true){ //Count int
     k = line.indexOf(t1, k+1);
     if (k<0) break;
     c1++;
    }
    while(true){
     if (Character.isWhitespace(text.charAt(i)) {
            whitespaceCount++;
        }

    }
   }
  }

Comment: `while (in.hasNext()){
      String line = in.nextLine();
      int a = line.length() - line.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
      System.out.println(a);
         //add code
      
     }`

The above code will print spaces for each line in the file. If you want it for whole file you can always add the sum

Comment: Thank you for solve my problem but, I have a last question to ask you.

If I want to detect the word "int" and count whitespace in a set of string per  word "int" like "int a = 0;" and if I have 4 ints declare in my source code how can i print the number of whitespace in set of string "int"
Ex. 

int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;

output: 
int a have 3 whitespaces
int b have 3 whitespaces
int c have 3 whitespaces
int d have 3 whitespaces

Thank you very much for answer my question.